# Python update plots in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, census

I want to plot some [Census Data](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs) on a US map to achieve something like this: [https://censusreporter.org/data/map/?table=B23025&geo_ids=01000US,040|01000US&primary_geo_id=01000US](https://censusreporter.org/data/map/?table=B23025&geo_ids=01000US,040%7C01000US&primary_geo_id=01000US)

But unlike the above link, I want to create an animation where I update the plot in a loop for different years.
This is what I have till now:

```
def StatesPlot(df, data, start_year, end_year, cmap):
    for year in range(start_year, end_year+1):
        f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10, 5.4), sharex=True, sharey=True, dpi=300)
        f.tight_layout()
        plt.title('United States Map - Variable: ' + data + ' Year: ' +str(year), fontsize=12)
        ax.set_axis_off()
        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="3%", pad=0, alpha=0.1)
        clear_output(wait=True)
        tmp = df[df['YEAR'] == year]
        tmp.plot(data, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='k', legend=True, cax=cax, linewidth=0.1)
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(1)

StatesPlot(us_cont, 'EMPLOYMENT_STATUS', 2015, 2019, 'viridis')
```

This works fine. The issues is that I wanted to create this animation to compare census data for different years, but as of now, this also updated the scale (`cax`) everytime, so I can't compare the data. How can I fix the scale outside of the loop and just update the plot?

Comment: Have you looked at any of Matplotlib's animation examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to set the max and min values for the colorbar in your `tmp.plot` line using the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments. Try adding something like this before your loop:

```
datamin = df[data].min()
datmax = df[data].max()
```

And then changing your plot line to reflect those limits:

```
tmp.plot(data, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, cmap=cmap, 
         edgecolor='k', legend=True, cax=cax, 
         linewidth=0.1, vmin=datamin, vmax=datamax)
```